# Javascript: Get subclass type in superclass

Tags: javascript

I am using [this](http://ejohn.org/blog/simple-javascript-inheritance/) to create a few classes and to set up some inheritance structure.

```
var ControlType = Class.extend({
    init: function(){ },

    html: function(type){
        //Get template based on name of subclass
    }
});

var YesNo = ControlType.extend({
    init: function(){ },
    html: function() {
        this._super('YesNo')
    }
});
```

Now I was wonder if it's possible to get the type of the subclass in `ControlType.html` without passing it explicitly?

### Update:

I tried `this.constructor` without the extend functionality as someone suggested but this returns the type of the parent class. So in the following example the console logs Person() but I need Jimi().

```
function Person(){
    this.say = function(){
        console.log(this.constructor);
    }
}

function Jimi(){
    this.name = 'Jimi';
}
Jimi.prototype = new Person();

var j = new Jimi();
j.say();
```

Comment: Which JS library are you using? I don't remember pure javascript having a `Class.extend` function.

Comment: Seems Stack Overflow ate my <a> tag. I fixed it now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hard to pick since there are actually a few different ways you could do this.  I guess maybe the easiest would be something like this:

```
function Person(){
    this.name = 'Person'; //<<< ADDED THIS
    this.say = function(){
        console.log(this.name);  //<<< ADDED THIS
    }
}

function Jimi(){
    this.name = 'Jimi';
}
Jimi.prototype = new Person();

var j = new Jimi();
j.say();
```

This will then output

```
Jimi
```

Hopefully it helps!

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Seems I was heading to the same solution in my own code.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are using some kind of inheritance library. I'm not sure what `extend` does, but in plain JavaScript, you can use `this.constructor` to refer to the constructor function of an object.